# Lightning Web Component does not display fetched data

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to display data that I got from the controller:

```
public class AccountController{
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static List<Account> callGetAccount(){
            List<Account> accountsList = new List<Account>();
            accountsList = [SELECT Name FROM Account];
            return accountsList;
        }
    }
```

I try to display it on the following HTML template of a Lightning Web Component:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="All Accounts">
          <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
            <template if:false={showAccounts}>
                <lightning-button label="Back" onclick={handleBackButtonClick}></lightning-button>
            </template>

            <template if:true={showAccounts}>
              <lightning-card>
                <template if:true={accounts}>
                  <lightning-datatable
                  key-field="Id"
                  data={accounts}
                  columns={ACCOUNT_COLUMNS}
                  hide-checkbox-column="true"
                  onrowaction={handleAccountRowAction}>
                  </lightning-datatable>
                </template>
              </lightning-card>
            </template>

            <template if:true={showPojazdy}>
              <lightning-card>
                <template if:true={pojazdy.data}>
                  <lightning-datatable
                  key-field="Id"
                  data={pojazdy.data}
                  columns={pojazdy_columns}
                  hide-checkbox-column="true"
                  onrowaction={handlePojazdRowAction}>
                  </lightning-datatable>
                </template>
              </lightning-card>
            </template>

            <template if:true={error}>
              <div class="slds-text-color_error">
                An error occured while loading the list
              </div>
            </template>
          </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

with the underlying JS file:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import callGetAccount from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.callGetAccount';
import ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
import callGetSalon from '@salesforce/apex/SalonController.callGetSalon';
import SALON_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Salon__c.Name';
import callGetPojazd from '@salesforce/apex/PojazdController.callGetPojazd';
import POJAZD_SERIAL_NUMBER_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Pojazd__c.Numer_seryjny__c';
import POJAZD_UPDATE_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/PojazdUpdate__c';
import POJAZD_REFRESH_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/PojazdRefresh__c';
import { publish, subscribe, unsubscribe, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';

const ACCOUNTS_ACTIONS = [{label: 'Pokaż salony', name: 'pokaz_salony'}];
const ACCOUNTS_COLUMNS = [{label: 'Nazwa firmy', fieldName: ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: "text"},
{
    type: "action",
    typeAttributes: {"rowActions": ACCOUNTS_ACTIONS},
}];

const SALONY_ACTIONS = [{label: "Pokaż samochody", name : 'pokaz_samochody'}];
const SALONY_COLUMNS = [{label: "Nazwa salonu", fieldName: SALON_NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: "text"},
{
    type: "action",
    typeAttributes: {rowActions: SALONY_ACTIONS}
}];

const POJAZDY_ACTIONS = [{label: "Pokaż szczegóły", name: "pokaz_szczegoly"}];
const POJAZDY_COLUMNS = [{label: "Numer seryjny", fieldName: POJAZD_SERIAL_NUMBER_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: "text" }, {
    type: "action",
    typeAttributes: {rowActions: POJAZDY_ACTIONS}
}];

export default class AccountList extends LightningElement {
    accounts_columns = ACCOUNTS_COLUMNS;
    @wire(callGetAccount) 
    wiredAccount({data, error}) { console.log(data); console.log(error);
     if (data) { this.accounts = data;
         this.error = undefined;
         }
      else if (error) { 
          this.error = error; 
          this.data = undefined; 
        }}
        
    accounts;
    salony_columns = SALONY_COLUMNS;
    searchAccountId = '';
    @wire(callGetSalon, {accountId: '$searchAccountId'})
    salony;
    searchSalonId = '';
    pojazdy_columns = POJAZDY_COLUMNS;
    @wire(callGetPojazd, {salonId: '$searchSalonId'})
    pojazdy;
    @wire(MessageContext) messageContext;
    showAccounts = true;
    showSalony = false;
    showPojazdy = false;

    handleBackClick(event) {
        if (this.showSalony) {
            this.showAccounts = true;
            this.showSalony = false;
        } else if (this.showPojazdy) {
            this.showSalony = true;
            this.showPojazdy = false;
        }
    }

    handleAccountRowAction(event) {
        const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
        const row = event.detail.row;
        switch (actionName) {
            case 'show_salony':
                this.searchAccountId = row.External_ID__c;
                this.showSalony = true;
                this.showAccounts = false;
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    handleSalonRowAction(event) {
        const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
        const row = event.detail.row;
        switch (actionName) {
            case 'show_cars':
                this.searchShowroomId = row.External_ID__c;
                this.showCars = true;
                this.showShowrooms = false;
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    handlePojazdRowAction(event) {
        const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
        const row = event.detail.row;
        switch (actionName) {
            case 'show_details':
                this.loadPojazd(row);
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    loadPojazd(selectedPojazd) {
        if (selectedPojazd) {
            const message ={
                car: selectedPojazd
            }; 
            publish(this.messageContext, POJAZD_UPDATE_MESSAGE, message);
        }
    }

    @wire(MessageContext)
    messageContext;
    connectedCallback() {
        this.subscription = subscribe(
            this.messageContext,
            POJAZD_REFRESH_MESSAGE,
            (message) => {
                if(message.refresh){
                    this.searchSalonId = this.searchSalonId;
                }
            });
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        unsubscribe(this.subscription);
        this.subscription = null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the component is supposed to display all accounts, but displays nothing. The data is fetched correctly from the database, as seen in the console. What is the problem here?

Comment: just a pointer, you might want to consider re-organizing your .js file and group your data by types (properties together, event handlers, wired functions, then functions, then getters/setters ) as is, the code seems a bit messy

Comment: try instantiate accounts as empty list and annotate with @track, `@track accounts = [];`.